# Use ABH formated Genetic map to scaffold contig level genome assembly to Scafold level assembly

Tags: scaffolding

[tag:AllMAPS,Scafolding,Geneticmap,ABH format]

I  have a Genetic map (18000_markers.csv) in ABH format and i want to use this genetic map to scaffold a contig level assembly(I have 2 haplotype phased genome assembly).

I figured out that this can be achived using ALLMAPS .But the input file in all maps looks different than what i posses and i am new to using genetic map and don't know how to convert the file that i have to be used to scaffold the haplotype phased genomes.

I have below an image showing the file i have I did not make an example small file to keep the data intact in the image and i don't know how to attach the .csv file for convenience.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9C8S.jpg)

To Allmaps format

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h48Yp.png)
Please let me know how can i scaffold the genome. Thanks in advance for your valuable time.

I cannot understand how to extract the information needed to use allmaps from the ABH.csv file that i have or convert the file to compatible input file for allmaps.